# Reorder consecutive integers in blocks using R

Tags: r, random, vector

I have a vector of the numbers 1:17. I am randomly reordering subset vectors within it (the example below is where 1:10 and 11:17 must be randomly reordered):

```
x = c(1:10)
x_s = sample(x, length(x), replace = FALSE)
[1]  7  9  3  4 10  5  1  6  8  2
y=c(11:17)
> y_s = sample(y, length(y), replace = FALSE)
[1] 17 16 13 12 14 15 11
final=c(x_s,y_s)
[1]  7  9  3  4 10  5  1  6  8  2 17 16 13 12 14 15 11
```

While I am able to get my final reordered vector, is there a more elegant approach to this code? I am asking because this is just an example, and my real problem is a much larger vector with many more sub-vectors within it that need random reordering. The code would be too many lines!

Thank you.

Comment: How are the subsets determined?

Comment: For this exact example, you could just do `unlist(lapply(list(1:10, 11:17), sample))`.

Comment: Just an fyi, when assigning consecutive integers `x <- c(1:10)`, you don't need to use `c()`.  `x <- 1:10` is just the same.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! @AnandaMahto: The subsets are a bit weird: The first subset is 1 and 52. The second subset is 2-51. Third subset is 53-102. Fourth to 23rd subsets are consecutive subsets of length 26 (i.e. 103-128, 129-154, ..., 675-700)

Comment: So, it is "subsets" not "substrings" because of the first subset (1 and 52) I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so using Ananda Mahto's suggestion on your set of sequences and using lapply (twice) and seq (twice) to build the sequences in list format:

```
unlist(
 lapply( c( list(x= c(1,52),y= 2:51,z= 53:103) ,    
            lapply( seq(103, 675, by=26), seq, len=25) ) ,
        sample)
       )
```

The argument to the outer lapply looks like this:

```
List of 26
 $ x: num [1:2] 1 52
 $ y: int [1:50] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
 $ z: int [1:51] 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 519 520 521 522 523 524 525 526 527 528 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 545 546 547 548 549 550 551 552 553 554 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 580 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 597 598 599 600 601 602 603 604 605 606 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 623 624 625 626 627 628 629 630 631 632 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 649 650 651 652 653 654 655 656 657 658 ...
 $  : num [1:25] 675 676 677 678 679 680 681 682 683 684 ...
```